# Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I couldn't run my projects because when I'm trying to do that there is an error message:
Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo
and when I see details, this is showed me up:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Gradle plugin missing from the offline Maven repo
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.plugin.AndroidPluginGeneration.getLatestKnownVersion(AndroidPluginGeneration.java:213)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.plugin.AndroidPluginGeneration$1.getLatestKnownVersion(AndroidPluginGeneration.java:68)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PluginVersionUpgrade.log(PluginVersionUpgrade.java:64)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PluginVersionUpgrade.checkAndPerformUpgrade(PluginVersionUpgrade.java:51)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.setup.post.PostSyncProjectSetup.setUpProject(PostSyncProjectSetup.java:163)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.lambda$populate$2(Projects.java:182)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeAndWaitIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2453)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.populate(Projects.java:168)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.Projects.populate(Projects.java:120)
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.lambda$populateProject$1(ProjectSetUpTask.java:120)
at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runWhenProjectIsInitialized$5(StartupManagerImpl.java:370)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$6.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:291)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:326)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:310)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:631)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you updated to Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1?

If so, I also had the same problem. They moved some things to their new repository: https://maven.google.com

So I had to add the following code in my build.gradle file

```
repositories {
  maven {
   url "https://maven.google.com"
  }
}
```

Also, still in the gradle, I had to update maually the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Finally, the gradle-wrapper needed also to be updated:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this problem by deleting folder "gradle" in root directory of Android Studio, running File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio and then copying folder "gradle" to root directory of Android Studio from freshly downloaded same version of Android Studio. And then restarting Android Studio again.

I am not claiming it is a right way to solve this problem, but it worked for me - Android Studio alphas and betas are not stable versions.